# Rails 4, not sending email using sendmail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, ruby-on-rails-4

I am having an issue sending out mail using rails 4 on Debian.

production.rb

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method       = :sendmail
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries    = true
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
```

controller.rb

`ReviewConfirm.confirm(@review).deliver`

rails debug output

```
D, [2014-08-16T09:09:35.851905 #2339] DEBUG -- : 
ReviewConfirm#confirm: processed outbound mail in 29.0ms
I, [2014-08-16T09:09:35.951972 #2339]  INFO -- : 
Sent mail to mypersonaladdress@gmail.com (99.4ms)
D, [2014-08-16T09:09:35.952421 #2339] DEBUG -- : Date: Sat, 16 Aug 2014 09:09:35 +0000
From: info@mypersonaldomain.com
To: mypersonaladdress@gmail.com
```

The server is able to send out email, using the command line and PHP. Mail logs are empty for an unknown reason. If anyone could shed any light on this, that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, turns out

`config.action_mailer.delivery_method       = :sendmail` should be `config.action_mailer.delivery_method       = :smtp`

Comment: smtp and sendmail are 2 possible different delivery methods. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#action-mailer-configuration